# ExtJS4 store mapping NPE

Tags: extjs4

When using the Ext.data.Store 'mapping' config property, of 'x.y', and the mapped model does not contain an 'x' property, the store throws an exception, which, prevents the store data from rendering into the grid view on data store load.

If the store source is out of your control, is it possible to avoid/catch the exception when the  root of the mapping path does not exist. I've tried using a 'convert' function for the target property of the data store. The mapping path into the JSON document is only determined from the run context [e.g. this.mappingPath]. Dynamically generating the convert function (to catch the exception) seems to slow down the page a bit.

Is there a solution to null results along the model's mapping path within the ExtJS API, or is catching the exception from within the convert function the way to go? Or possibly another solution...

Comment: u r going to have to post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using a convert function with a call to a 'followPath' type function anywhere that this was the case. Follow path breaks up the mapping component into it's parts (split on '.') and iterates through the list readjusting the context to context = context[part] along the way. so the call is followPath(item.data,path). This performs well, and gets the job done.